# How to write php code insite double quotation of href in php?

Tags: php, html

I am having difficulty to find out correct quote patterns to inside href to write PHP code. I checked other StackOverflow questions but did not get any idea. I am displaying data in PHP using table written inside PHP code rather then in HTML. Can anyone help me please? Thanks

```
"<td><a href='reps.php?id=<?php echo $data['userID']?>'". $data["userID"]. "</a></td></tr>";
```

Comment: You do not "open" PHP again, you are already in a PHP block. Use the `.` operator to concat strings and variables.

Comment: @Progman Following your advice will lead to [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). It's the wrong approach.

Comment: @Progman Thanks for your help. just one question the line is already echo but I am not displaying id in URL its just showing empty. and if I add echo then its giving me an error.

Comment: perhaps something like this: <td><a href="reps.php?id=<?php echo {$data['userID']} . {$data['userID']};?>"></a></td></tr>;  -- you are using double quotes " before your html? no need.... also you didn't close your php with ;?> see my example